# Issue Updating one Html.TextBoxFor based on value of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use some very simple jQuery to change the text of one textbox to be half of the numeric value of another textbox's text.

My Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#InventoryValue').keyup(function () {
        var stringValue = $(this).text;
        var floatValue = (parseFloat(stringValue).toFixed(2)) / 2;
        $('#FiftyPercentMultiplier').text(floatValue);
    });
});
</script>
```

My Textboxes are defined as so:

```
 <tr>
     <td>
         <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.InventoryValue, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</b>
     </td>
     <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InventoryValue, new { id = "InventoryValue" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InventoryValue)
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>
         <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FiftyPercentMultiplier, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</b>
     </td>
     <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FiftyPercentMultiplier, new { id = "FiftyPercentMultiplier" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FiftyPercentMultiplier)
     </td>
</tr>
```

Rendered TextBoxes:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *Competitive Inventory Value: must be a number." id="InventoryValue" name="InventoryValue" type="text" value="" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *50% (.50) Multiplier: must be a number." id="FiftyPercentMultiplier" name="FiftyPercentMultiplier" type="text" value="" />
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I've spent the last 2 hours at work smashing my head over this!

Comment: and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

```
$('#FiftyPercentMultiplier').val(floatValue);
```

Comment: @kmsdev I changed both calls of text() to val(). The event is triggering as I would expect, except for the fact that the second text box always displays NaN. Am I using parseFloat incorrectly?

Comment: I am seeing that `$(this)` is a form element, since you are using its `onkeyup` event, so to get its value properly, you have to use `.val()` in that case too. Then, the correct would be `var stringValue = $(this).val();`. If changing it the issue persists, please, update your question with the current code. @BrennanMorell